# How to mark Launch as changed?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I want to trigger a `ILaunchListener.launchChanged` event from inside an `IProcess` belonging to the `ILaunch`

How do I trigger a `launchChanged` event programatically, in this context?

EDIT: an `org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunch` can have afferent processes of type `org.eclipse.debug.core.model.IProcess`. When something happens inside the `IProcess` instance I want the `ILaunch` to access the `launchChanged` of all the `ILaunchListeners` registered on the `LaunchManager`

Comment: Do you mean from inside the program that has been launched?

Comment: Yes, the IProcess instance that was added to the ILaunch instance. I added the packages of the classes I am using. Did I answer your question?     Many thanks.

Comment: Not really. The `IProcess` is code running in Eclipse that represents the program that has been launched. The actual program is running in a separate JVM and can't easily change anything in Eclipse.

Comment: It is seemingly not obligatory that the IProcess runs on a separate JVM. In this example it is on the same JVM, at least.